# Should I add line breaks within 78 characters when I send email?

Tags: professionalism, email, business

Should I add line breaks every line in email?

Nowadays, people use wide range of devices such as mobile, table and laptop.

If I add line breaks in email, line will be broken in the middle of the line depends on the size of the screen (especially mobile)

But if I don't add line breaks , recipients can change the location of line breaks as he change the size of the window.

I think no line break is better because if I add them, it is hard to read the email using mobile

I know that some people say that to add line breaks is kind of etiquette when you send 'polite' email.

Which is the standard nowadays?

Comment: It is far better to trust the various email programs to handle this. The big companies which code them know far more about various devices than you do. For instance, are you even sure that 78 chars is not too wide or some devices?

Comment: You may want to use less blank lines in your e-mail than the rather large amount in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Add line breaks at the end of paragraphs.  Allow the different devices to handle reformatting lines as they need to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That is the same Idea what I am thinking of. But all people think the same way?

Comment: I think in 90s and 2000s, add line breaks all lines is kind of etiquette . When the rule changed?

Comment: I think the rules evolved over time as the number of different types of devices and programs to read email grew so large

Comment: @Nagginagaseyoshi 25+ years ago most email users were still using plaintext only clients that either didn't support any sort of auto line breaking, or did so at only the most primitive and problematic level. (Farther back that became all clients.) Email etiquette from then was written around the limitations of those clients (and generally you wanted to stay around 70 characters for line lengths so that several levels of `> ` quoting could be done without problem.

Comment: Inertia kept the old rules around for a while; but by 15 or 10 years ago people using those clients had become a tiny minority;  and trying to comply in html clients with variable width fonts is very cumbersome.  Meanwhile newer clients had gotten better at formatting and reflowing text for arbitrary width displays; but were still not perfect.  Stuffing arbitrary line breaks in the middle of paragraphs was only a source of potential failure with them.  Meanwhile a growing portion of the user base had never used old text clients.

Comment: At which point - having gone from something that everyone needed to do, to something you did as a courtesy for a significant fraction of your recipients, to something weird that would break things - the practice gradually faded away.

Comment: An alternative solution: Just keep your e-mails brief (each paragraph < 78 characters) and it will be a non-issue.